# Obter dados de um arquivo HTML inserido no input

Tags: javascript, html, html5, node.js, input

Eu tenho um input que irá receber um outro arquivo HTML.

```
<input type="file" id="uploadHTML" class="form-control">
```

Vamos supor que o input está no arquivo `index.html` e que eu vou inserir nele o arquivo `Arquivo.html`, dessa forma aqui:
[Arquivo.html dentro do input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRcyk.png)

Depois de obter esse arquivo, eu gostaria de executar esse código dentro do `Arquivo.html` para obter o conteúdo das tags `<p>` que estão no arquivo sem ter que abrir ele:

```
var lstP = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i <= lstP.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(lstP[i].innerText)
}
```

E depois, em outro momento, eu gostaria de executar esse código dentro do mesmo arquivo:

```
var grupo = document.getElementsByClassName('group')
grupo[0].parentNode.removeChild(grupo[0])
```

Até o momento, meu código está assim:

```
var inputHTML = document.querySelector("#uploadHTML")

inputHTML.addEventListener('change', async function () {
    const arquivo = this.files[0]
})
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?
Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Não precisa ser necessariamente com esses códigos, o importante é extrair o texto de dentro da tag <p>

Answer (score 0):

### Resposta

```html
<label for="uploadHTML">Select a file:</label>
<input type="file" id="uploadHTML" name="uploadHTML" />
```

Código javascript

```js
const fileSelector = document.getElementById('uploadHTML');

fileSelector.addEventListener('change', async (event) => {
  // List of uploaded files
  const fileList = event.target.files;

  // Get text content of the first file in the list
  const htmlFileContentString = await fileList[0].text();

  // Convert the HTML string into a document object
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(htmlFileContentString, 'text/html');

  // Get p tags content
  const lstP = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('p');
  for (let i = 0; i <= lstP.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(lstP[i].innerText);
  }
});
```

### Explicações

Use a variável `htmlDoc` para manipular o conteúdo html do arquivo que foi feito upload, essa variável terá acesso a todos métodos disponíveis no objeto document. Por isso no código uso

```js
const lstP = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('p');
```

ao invés de

```js
const lstP = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
```

#### Links úteis

https://gomakethings.com/getting-html-with-fetch-in-vanilla-js/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js#21870431